# Is there an application which let me crop a picture on my device into the correct size to use as wallpaper

Tags: images, wallpaper

Do you know of **software** which can **crop a photo** or an image **into the correct size to act as wallpaper** ?

Now, if I download an image from the net  and try to use it as a wallpaper ( *long pressing an image in a web browser, let's you use it as a wallpaper* ), it always uses the top of the image. Depending on the picture, this makes a lot of pictures useless.

I could imagine a graphic application which let's met **select a portion of an image** ( the correct size for the device I'm running it on ), and than **saves the cropped version and sets it as a wallpaper**.

I am not so much interested into a graphic editing program on Android as such ( I will do graphic editing on the PC ), unless it gives me the option I am asking.

I am using an Archos 101 tablet running Froy 2.2.1 , if that should make a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save the image to  SD Card and use the **Gallery app** to set the wallpaper. Gallery app has the feature to crop selected portion of an image and then save it as a wallpaper.

Comment: Indeed. Never knew this program had that feature. I'm learning something new every day !

Answer (score 2):

Also **QuickPic** application can cut a picture to correct size before set it as wallpaper. It's free on [Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder).